# Python pandas, filter our data with isin and other conditions

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, isin

I have tried to use below codes to filter out records from a `dataframe`, for data is either with item codes 04901 or 04940 and Year is in 2022. However, this is not work property, it only return nil data, not sure why this is not work as intended, this only return no record.

```
df.loc[(df['Item Code'].isin(['04901', '04940'])) & (df['Year'] == '2022')]
```

If anybody can get me a hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If years are integers use `2022` instead `'2022'`:

```
df[(df['Item Code'].isin(['04901', '04940'])) & (df['Year'] == 2022)]
```

Or:

```
df[df['Item Code'].isin(['04901', '04940']) & df['Year'].eq(2022)]
```

Comment: Thanks, IIUC, I have taken out "loc", however still return not record

Comment: Also, it I break down into 2 steps, there are records returned

Comment: @Bobzy3721 Can you provide print of  `df.loc[df['Item Code'].isin(['04901', '04940']), 'Year'].unique()`?

Comment: Thanks all, 2022 is working, should not be '2022'

Comment: @Bobzy3721 - If use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) then `loc` is not necessary.